# Is wildcard import considered "acceptable" when using it to allow folder structure in step definition container?

Tags: python, selenium

Currently I'm working on automation in a project that has a very big site divided in sections and/or pages.
I'm using python-behave for the first time and I'm still learning (used to work with ProtractorJS)

Since I started I've been using the steps folder to put all my step files (each page has it's own step file) but in my case, it's not going to be scalable since the site has around 50 pages, with subsections each, so having all step files in one folder is going to get messy as I start adding files to the step folder.

What I want to do is be able to have folders to separate each of the pages and have step files in each of them to better organize the files. 
Now, I know that this framework does not support having a folder structure inside the step definition folder, so i started looking around and found [this post](https://aditamasblog.wordpress.com/2018/07/18/setup-pythons-behave-library-to-read-steps-from-subfolders/) with a possible solution, but i noticed he uses wildcard import to add all nested step files. 
I know wildcard imports are not considered a good practice in general, but i feel in this case is the only way to allow folder strucures for step files.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Example
features
  -->steps
    ---->*.py // This is where pyhton-behave expects to find the step definitions. The "recommended" way

What i'm trying to do
features
  --->steps 
    ----->login
        -------->login_steps.py
    ----->some_page
        -------->some_pages_steps.py
  --->all_steps.py // file that imports nested step files using wildcard
               // the only file that behave finds when looking for steps

Comment: Best Practice != Never do it. I think you've found a valid exception to this rule. If it works and doesn't cause you any troubles then use it.